# Virtual accessor for Thinking Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Can I set a virtual accessor in model and set this accessor as field or attribute in Thinking Sphinx? I'm trying like this but getting error "undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
"
index model:

```
...
has price_in_base_currency
```

and in model:

```
..
attr_accessible :price
attr_accessor :price_in_base_currency

belongs_to :currency

before_save :set_accessor

def set_accessor
 price_in_base_currency = price * currency.rate
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this with clear sql :

```
has "GROUP_CONCAT((price * currencies.rate) SEPARATOR ',')", :as => "price_in_base_currency", :type => :integer
```

Comment: You don't need the GROUP_CONCAT if it's a single value (as opposed to a collection/multi-value-attribute). And Sphinx connects via SQL, so your model objects (and Ruby generally) are not involved in the indexing process.